# scalac doesn't find the right insert method in org.squeryl.Table

Tags: scala, generics, compiler-errors, squeryl, method-call

I am trying to write a class that does generic inserts and updates of any entity type with Squeryl, following certain rules.

I have it compiling when it just calls `update` on a `Table[E]`, but when I call `insert` on that same `Table[E]`, *with the same argument*, the compiler complains that I'm passing in a `T`, not a `org.squeryl.Query[T]`.

But there is a method in `org.squeryl.Table` called `insert` that takes a `T` as an argument!

It's not even an inherited method. It's right there in `org.squeryl.Table`!

It doesn't have any constraints or other implicit arguments.

How could scalac get something so simple so wrong?

I thought Eclipse might have been confused, but I get exactly the same result from building the project in `sbt`.

Comment: Wait... I think this might be due to scalac inferring the return type. Need to look at my code to check, but I don't have it in front of me right now.

Comment: You should propably put the question "on hold".

Comment: @VasyaNovikov I don't have the power to do that alone, it would require a vote of 5 people. But there's no need, because I will look at my code in a couple of hours.

Comment: If that doesn't solve the issue for you, please add some code snippets to the question.  It will help us track down the issue for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been caused by scalac narrowing the set of methods I could be calling based on the inferred return type. I needed to write the next line, which returns a value from the method (this was inside an `if...else`).

This is really unintuitive behaviour in the context of an IDE, in which the code is typechecked as soon as you type it. Instead of writing the next line, I was focusing on trying to fix the type error - which was merely a transient problem.